# Bus error when appending to C array

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I'm running into a bus error trying to do a manual concatenation of two strings without library functions (school assignment). Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcattest(char string1[ ], char string2[ ]);

int main() {
    printf("*****STRING CONCATENATION*****\n");
    printf("Hello plus Hello: %s\n", strcattest("Hello","Hello"));
    printf("Hello plus Hellp: %s\n", strcattest("Hello","Hellp"));
    printf("Helo plus Hello: %s\n", strcattest("Helo","Hello"));
    printf("Hello plus Helo: %s\n", strcattest("Hello","Helo"));

    return(0);
}

char *strcattest(char string1[ ], char string2[ ]) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(string1[counter]!='\0') {
        counter++;
    }
    int str2counter = 0;
    while(string2[str2counter]!='\0') {
        string1[counter] = string2[str2counter];
        str2counter++;
        counter++;
    }
    string1[counter]='\0';
    return string1;
}
```

I've done some research and I think I understand conceptually why this does not work. (I'm calling trying to modify a variable -- string1 -- that is based on a static string.) However, I'm not sure how to rectify this so that it behaves itself. I tried introducing a local variable in the strcattest function that would behave as a copy of string1 but that got the compiler yelling at me for returning a local variable from a function.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you are trying to modify a static (read-only) string; doing this is what the C standard terms "undefined behaviour" (which in your case manifests as a crash).

To fix this, you need to allocate a character array that you can modify. You can do this either statically (on the stack) or dynamically (using `malloc`).

Statically, to initialize a character array with specific content, you can do

```
char mystring[1024] = "Hello!";
```

This will initialize the character array with the string contents, copying them (note that the similar-looking `char *mystring = "Hello!";` is *not* an array initialization, and will instead make `mystring` point to the static string). You can place that declaration either at global scope (outside of any function, not recommended unless you have a specific reason to use a global), or in your `main` method (then you can pass it to `strcattest`).

Dynamically, the declaration looks like

```
char *mystring = malloc(1024);
```

to get an uninitialized buffer big enough to hold 1024 characters (counting the null terminator). If you `malloc` something, though, you have to `free` it later, or you'll end up with a memory leak. To put something in it, do

```
strcpy(mystring, "Hello!");
```

Note that `mystring = "Hello!"` in this case won't work: why not?

Comment: Because it once again is using the static definition of the string rather than the one that is represented as a character array? (Not sure if that's right, but either way this answer really helped me at least start to get my head around this concept...thanks very much!)

Comment: Yes! `mystring = "Hello!"` will make `mystring` point at the static string again. Keep at it: it'll all make sense soon :)

Answer (score 1):

You try concatenate a string literal to *another* string literal. Those string literals are, besides being too short, *read only*.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

```
printf("Hello plus Hello: %s\n", strcattest("Hello","Hello"));
```

The strings `"Hello"` here are string literals and are placed in implementation defined (read only) memory. You cannot modify them.Modifying them would lead to **Undefined Behavior**. So you cannot append a string literal to another simply, because they are not meant to be modifyable.

**The Solution:**

If you want to get an string sppended with the two string literals then you need to do the following:

1. Have a pointer to dynamically memory allocated(malloc) buffer in your function.
2. Append the string literals inside this buffer, You can modify its contensts since the memory is owned by you.
3. Return pointer to this dynamically allocated memory.
4. Don't forget to deallocate(free) the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The "Hello" argument you pass to the function actually resides in the .data section of your program. You are not allowed to modify this section. Any attempts to do so can give you errors (bus error in your case).

You are only allowed to manipulate that part of your memory which is in the stack (local variables and arrays) or heap (memory allocated using [mc]alloc() functions).